# Where is the use of "\\?\" defined?

Tags: windows, cmd

This command is to delete all files and sub-folders in a folder

```
rd /s "\\?\D:\TestFolder
```

This command snippet got from a youtube video right [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4IQCZ5dKMw)

Could someone explain what this, `\\?\`, does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the prefix to bypass Windows path normalization. With it you'll be able to access paths that are not valid in Win32 namespace like names ending with `.` or spaces: `D:\TestFolder\folder ending with space \file name ending with dot.`, or files with path longer than MAX_PATH (260 characters in older Windows)

> For file I/O, the `"\\?\"` prefix to a path string tells the Windows APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows it straight to the file system. For example, if the file system supports large paths and file names, you can exceed the `MAX_PATH` limits that are otherwise enforced by the Windows APIs. For more information about the normal maximum path limitation, see the previous section [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation).
>
> [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces - Win32 File Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-file-namespaces)

See

- [Dots at the end of file name?](https://superuser.com/q/230385/241386)
- [How to copy files that have too long of a filepath in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/216704/241386)

Comment: i have 2 questions then:

1. so this prefix will send the string after, directly to file system, like exactly? what if some folder containing characters like ", so we dont have to escape it with \ ?

Comment: 2. the reference link you mention there, "\\?\", the video showing "\\?\ without ending with another " (double quote), still works?

Comment: obviously you still need to escape it somehow at the shell level, because it's the shell who passes the command line to the running process or shell's builtin command, and if the shell sees `"` as a special character then it'll treat it differently

Comment: The fact that sometimes unbalanced quoting works is just a legacy thing in cmd. Just try `dir C:\Windows` and `dir "C:\Windows` and they'll both work identically. It has nothing to do with this prefix because the shell doesn't care about that, only the running command sees the prefix. Cmd simply doesn't report an error in this case. I always recommend to use powershell for new code and avoid cmd completely

Comment: I note that PowerShell `Get-ChildItem -Path '\\?\C:\'` does not work. No errors. No results.

Comment: @lit you need to remove the final backslash: [Why doesn't PowerShell Test-Path work with “\\?\” prefix when passing a root-drive path?](https://superuser.com/q/1411444/241386)

Comment: @phuclv, `Get-ChildItem -Path '\\?\C:\'` does not work.

Comment: @lit did you even read the link above? Of course I'd known that PowerShell cmdlets won't work with the root folder, that why I asked that question. Yes the "remove the final backslash" part is my mistake, but the point stays